# How can I populate a db column upon clicking the verify email address button contained in the email?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'd like to know how I can populate the `email_verified_at` column with a timestamp upon the user clicking on the `Verify Email Address` contained in the verification email that's being sent.

I thought it'd be a straightforward thing to do hence my attempt below in the `EmailVerificationController.php` file but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Any feedback is appreciated :)

Here's `api.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function () {

Route::post('email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'sendVerificationEmail']);

Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}',            function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();
    return redirect('/');
})->name('verification.verify');

});
```

Here's `EmailVerificationController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;

class EmailVerificationController extends Controller
{
    public function sendVerificationEmail(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return [
                'message' => 'Already Verified'
            ];
        }

        $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return ['status' => 'verification-link-sent'];
    }

    public function verify(EmailVerificationRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return [
                'message' => 'Email already verified'
            ];
        } 

        if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
            $time             = Carbon::now();
            $timeStamp        = $time->toDateTimeString();

            User::create([
               'email_verified_at' => $timeStamp
            ]);
        }

        return [
            'message'=>'Email has been verified'
        ];
    }
}
```

Here's `AuthController.php`

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {

        try {
            $request->validate([
                'name'           => 'required',
                'email'          => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'age'            => 'required',
                'password'       => 'required|min:6',
            ]);

            $data                = $request->all();

            $dbData = [
                'name'           => $data['name'],
                'email'          => $data['email'],
                'age'            => $data['age'],
                'password'       => Hash::make($data['password'])
            ];

            $user                = User::create($dbData);

            event(new Registered($user));

            return response()->json([
                "status"         => true,
                "message"        => "Registered Successfully!",
                'token'          => $user->createToken('tokens')->plainTextToken
            ]);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Laravel’s Must Verify Email feature in the API registration

[Follow this tutorial](https://medium.com/@pran.81/how-to-implement-laravels-must-verify-email-feature-in-the-api-registration-b531608ecb99)

Comment: I've already done that in the User model but I'm going to check out this document. thanks